# Wi-Fi Connection Issue: Works with LAN but Not with Wi-Fi - Debian

Tags: wireless-networking, router, debian, wireless-router, connection

I'm facing an unusual Wi-Fi connectivity problem and could use some guidance to troubleshoot and resolve the issue. My setup is as follows: I have a functional internet connection when connected via LAN cable, but I'm unable to access the internet over Wi-Fi on a specific device. This worked before but stopped working suddenly. Other devices can connect to the same Wi-Fi network without any issues.

Issue Details:

Device: Debian 11

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Restarted router and modem.
Restarted the device.
Forgot and reconnected to Wi-Fi network.
Checked for MAC address filtering (not enabled).
Verified correct Wi-Fi password.
Updated Wi-Fi drivers.
Despite these efforts, the Wi-Fi connection on my device remains inactive. The traceroute to the router's default gateway (192.168.1.1) shows no response.

I'm seeking advice on further steps I can take to diagnose and resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: In Ubuntu, for some Linux kernels, I've had to rebuild to add WiFi drivers. Could the issue have occurred after an update?

Comment: I do updates regularly and yes I did updated before and the issue happended after restart next day. @DrMoishePippik

Comment: @JaromandaX I am using Spectrum Wifi. I am trying to acces internet in Debian OS in Dell.

Comment: @JaromandaX I am sorry. The wifi device in my system is "wlp6s0".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147948/discussion-between-itsmepvr-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Network Manager?  Connman? Systemd?
For wifi on Linux, I have found iwd easier to configure and more reliable than wpa_supplicant.
If you are running systemd, then you may have to change the /etc/systemd/wireless.network paramenters.
[ArchWiki on iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).